# In Jmeter using CSV data config element, when entering data like 'D12345' it is taking in the form in the field as "%22D12345%09%22"

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Data In the CSV file with Column name 'P' nad value in it :
Column Name = P
Value in it = D12345

And in the Request Body it is taking as = %22D12345%09%22
and in UI in the field it is showing as ="D12345 "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the data in CSV file has certain characters which are being [percent-encoded](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_aurlencode.asp), according to the table:

- `%22` - is `"` character
- `%09` is a horizontal tab ([tabulation character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key))

So

- if you don't want the characters to be present in the request body - remove them from the CSV file.
- if you want the characters to be present in the request body but in their original form - go for [__urldecode() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urldecode), see [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) article to learn more about [JMeter Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) concept.

  [image]

  or disable the encoding in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler